# compute character position over a data.frame

Tags: r

How do you change values on a row, in function of the position of a specific character ?

I want to replace, by row, all NA values by 0 that are BEFORE S on the line. After this specific character S, NAs on the row has to be keeped.

S is the marker of the end of data by row.

Before S: NA should be values (in fact zero values !!).

After S: NA stays NA, no values at all.

An example of data frame is available here [dataframe.txt](https://uqat-my.sharepoint.com/personal/nola07_uqat_ca/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fnola07%5Fuqat%5Fca%2FDocuments%2Ftest%2Etxt&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fnola07%5Fuqat%5Fca%2FDocuments&slrid=ebcda99e-d0eb-7000-97a0-2b9cc895b9ec)

I've tried this loop

```
for (i in 1:length(df)) {
    x <- pos = 's' ; y <- pos = i if (y < x) { if (y == "NA"){ replace(y,0) } } 
}
```

Maybe with the `which` function ...

Thanks for your ideas on that !!
Alex,

Comment: Why would you provide your code as an image? Please provide it as actual text. While you're at it, please provide a sample of your data with an example of what your desired output would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will replace all NAs before "S" with 0 in your vector:

```
initial_row <- c(1,2,4,NA,4,NA,2,"S",NA,NA,NA)

result_row <- initial_row
result_row[is.na(result_row[1:which(result_row == "S")[1]])] <- 0
```

Explanation: First we copied the initial row into the result row that we will do the work on.  Then we selected the NAs in the result row that are between position 1 and the position of the "S".  Those values get replaced with zero.

#### Important assumptions:

1. The vector is at least length 2.
2. The vector contains an "S"

#### Loop version

If you insist on using a loop to do this (will run slower), you can do this:

```
for(i in 1:length(result_row)){
  if(result_row[i] == "S"){
    break
  }
  if(is.na(result_row[i])){
    result_row[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Edit: If you have characters `"NA"` in your vector instead of `NA` (which R recognizes as a missing element) this code will need to be modified as such:

```
result_row[(result_row[1:which(result_row == "S")[1]]) == "NA"] <- 0
```

or

```
for(i in 1:length(result_row)){
  if(result_row[i] == "S"){
    break
  }
  if(result_row[i] == "NA"){
    result_row[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot KamRa, I see the logic here ! I've tried on my data and sadly it doesn't work ... maybe because there was a confusion between vector and dataframe ? I've put an example of txt file in the original post so you can see the actual structure of the data (very messy).

Comment: Hi Alex, I thought you were using vectors.  To make this work with a dataframe, replace the `result_row` with the row in your data frame.  For example, `my_data_frame[1,]` would reference the first row of your data frame as a vector.

Comment: Hi again Alex, see my edit in my answer to accommodate your character `"NA"`s instead of true `NA`s.

Comment: Hi again ! And thanks for these quick answers !! I got error messages using both of the codes... with loop : `Error in if (df[i, ] == "S") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. In addition: Warning message:
In if (df[i, ] == "S") { :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` and with the 1st code `Error in `[.data.frame`(df, 1:which(df == "S")[1]) : undefined columns selected `. I've specified dataframe rows with df[i,] as advised ... ;/ Thanks. Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, I unfortunately do not have enough information to solve this problem.  If I did not answer your question adequately, please provide more context so I can replicate your problem.  If I did answer your question, and this is a new problem unrelated to your original question, kindly accept my first answer and post a new question.