# Replacement of empty cells according to the position of a specific character in a data.frame

Tags: r

)

A `data.frame` contains an `S` character on each line, at a different position. How to replace empty cells before `S` with `0` (zeros); and empty cells after `S` by `NA`.

I've already tried this [compute character position over a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675583/compute-character-position-over-a-data-frame)

For every line of the `data.frame`, the initial conditions are : `;1;;1;S;;;;`
and the expected results would be : `0;1;0;1;S;NA;NA;NA;NA`

Happy holydays !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
df1[] <- t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) {
             i1 <- which(x == 'S')[1]
             x[seq_len(i1)][x[seq_len(i1)] == ''] <- 0
             i2 <- (i1+1):length(x)
             x[i2][x[i2]==''] <- NA
               x}))
```

---

Or use `max.col` to get the column index of the element 'S' in each row and then with `row/column` indexing assign the 0 values to those columns that are blank before the 'S' and subsequently, replace all other blank (`""`) with `NA`

```
i1 <- max.col(df1 == 'S', 'first')
i2 <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), i1), sequence(i1))
df1[i2][df1[i2]== ""] <- 0
df1[df1==""] <- NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(v1 = c(1L, 5L), v2 = c("", ""), v3 = c("", "S"
), v4 = c("S", ""), v5 = c("", ""), v6 = c("", "4"), v7 = c("", 
  "3"), v8 = c("", "")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```